# mysql amazon ec2 "Can't create test file" error

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I'm running on EC2, and want to have MYSQL's datadir on another EBS. I mounted the EBS (ext3) on /data and changed the datadir in my.cnf to point to that dir. However, when I try to start mysql, I get this error:

```
120518 03:53:17 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
120518 03:53:28 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /data/mysql/
120518  3:53:28 [Warning] Can't create test file /data/mysql/ip-10-136-23-225.lower-test
120518  3:53:28 [Warning] Can't create test file /data/mysql/ip-10-136-23-225.lower-test
/usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't change dir to '/data/mysql/' (Errcode: 13)
120518  3:53:28 [ERROR] Aborting

120518  3:53:28 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

120518 03:53:28 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

If you are running on a distro like Ubuntu, then AppArmor is probably blocking mysqld from being able to access files in a different directory.  If you check your system log files, you'll find a cryptic error message to this effect.

Solutions include:

1. Disable AppArmor (not recommended)
2. Edit the AppArmor rules (complicated)
3. Use "mount bind" to make MySQL think that your data files are in the original location while they are actually over on the EBS volume. Revert your changes to datadir.

I wrote an article for Amazon years back describing community best practices for exactly what you are trying to do including commands for the mount bind example:

> Running MySQL on Amazon EC2 with EBS
>   http://ec2ebs-mysql.notlong.com

Note that the AMI id in the article is old. Using a modern Ubuntu AMI, you'll need to replace /dev/sdh with /dev/xvdh in the mkfs.xfs and /etc/fstab (but not in the ec2 tools command lines).

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Ubuntu, you can run into this error due to the apparmor service. To get around this. To get around it, you need to do the following:

1) Edit '/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld' and add these lines:

```
/opt/lib/mysql/ r,

/opt/lib/mysql/** rwk,

( assuming your new data directory is in /opt/lib/mysql )
```

2) re-start the apparmor service:

```
sudo service apparmor restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Change owner of /data directory to mysqld process owner (chown owner /data ). or (chmod 777 -R /data) very unsafe.